# Set password of user in asp.net core 3.1 seeding

Tags: asp.net-identity

I want to seeding user and role inside of *ApplicationDbContext*:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole
        {
            Id = 1, //Is this OK?
            Name = "admin",
            NormalizedName = "ADMIN"
        });

        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasData(new IdentityUser
        {
            Id = 1,
            UserName = "admin1",
            Email = "a@a.com",
            PasswordHash = ??,
            SecurityStamp = ??
        });

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<string>
        {
            RoleId = 1,
            UserId = 1
        });
    }
```

1.Is it ok to set id of user and role to 1?

2.How can i generate PasswordHash and SecurityStamp??

I try this but when i enter username and password in login page it doesn't work

> Invalid login attempt.

```
var passHasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
var p = passHasher.HashPassword(user, "123456");
```

3.Is this a right way to use ModelBuilder or should i use UserManager to create user in seed?